# Why Nginx $ssl_preread_server_name throws an error "no host in upstream"

Tags: nginx

I am trying to do a forward proxy by site name.
My problem is that $ssl_preread_server_name throws an error in the log:

> **no host in upstream**

```
stream {

    upstream test1.mysite.com {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8200;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name;
    }
}
```

The traffic to the server comes from AWS Network Load balancer using TLS
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/